# Spyder - how to execute python script in the current console?

Tags: python, conda, spyder

I've updated conda and spyder to the latest versions.
I want to execute python scripts (using F5 hotkey) in the current console.
However, the new spyder behaves unexpectedly, for example, if I enter in a console `a=5` and then run test.py script that only contains a command `print(a)`, there is an error: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

In the configuration options (command+F6) I've checked "Execute in current console" option.
I am wondering why is this happening?

Conda 4.8.2, Spyder 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer:
In run configuration (command+F6) there is another option that needs to be checked: "Run in console's namespace instead of empty one"

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences, run settings, there is a "General settings", in which you can (hopefully still) deactivate "Remove all variables before execution".

I even think to remember that this is new, so it makes sense.

Comment: No, that was not the issue